# C#: Set font for UserControl (WinForm)

Tags: user-controls

I got a UserControl and some comboboxes in it. When I set new font for the UserControl, the font in comboboxes were also changed (this is expected) but the texts in them were selected!!
How can I prevent text selection in comboboxes?
Hope to find some solution soon.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can post your xaml here. 
If your bindings have something like this:
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
change it to false to prevent text selection.

Comment: It is not a wpf usercontrol but a normal Winform usercontrol with some editable comboboxes.

Comment: oh sry i missed the winform in your title. maybe you should add some additional taggs to your post :)